# Can I leave France while I am waiting for my visa extension?

Tags: visa, france

I am currently in France on a visitor carte de sejour. It is a one year visa. I am coming up on its expiration and I am still in the process of extending it/applying for a different one. I have not yet received the invitation to the prefecture for renewing my visa, therefore have no proof that I am in the midst of this process.

What happens if I stay in France after my visa expires? Does the 90 day visitor visa kick in? Do I have to leave France before it expires? If I choose to stay and wait for the prefecture's invitation, will I be able to leave France on an expired visa?

Thank you for any help,

Comment: It might be different depending on your préfecture but I've yet to hear of any that are so kind as to send you an "invitation" to renew your visa.  Normally you have to take it upon yourself to make an appointment with the préfecture for carte de séjour renewal.  They usually encourage you to make an appointment months in advance of your expiration date, as it can take a while to get one.  Depending on your préfecture you might be able to make an appointment online, or go in person to ask for an appointment.

Comment: To add to the comment by @Igananaut: which préfecture do you depend on and have you already made an appointment to renew your titre de séjour visiteur ? Or when you say "invitation" do you mean a "convocation" ? As Iguananaut said, you have to make the appointment for renewal at the préfecture yourself.